# Returning values from Callback

Tags: javascript

I don't have any previous javascript experience.

I'm trying to implement the following function which I wish to use to return the values lat and lng:

```
function get_address() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

    geocoder.geocode({ address: "SE-17270 Sverige"}, 
    function(locResult) {

    var lat = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();
    alert(lat);
    alert(lng);
    })
}
```

How do I do this?

So what I want to do is something like this:

```
      function get_address(postcode)
      {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()
        var lat
        var lng

        geocoder.geocode({ address: "SE-"+postcode+"Sverige"}, 
        function(locResult) {

            lat = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();
        })
        return lat,lng
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a callback to handle the geocoding results:

```
function myCallback(lat, lng) {
  // Process lat and lng.
}

function get_address(callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

    geocoder.geocode({ address: "SE-17270 Sverige"}, 
      function(locResult) {
          var lat = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
          var lng = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();
          callback(lat, lng);
      }
    );
}
....
get_address(myCallback);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use global variables or return the values in an array for instance:

**global variables method:**

```
lat = "";
lng = "";

function get_address() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

    geocoder.geocode({ address: "SE-17270 Sverige"}, 
    function(locResult) {

    lat = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
    lng = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();
    alert(lat);
    alert(lng);
    })
}
```

**array method:**

```
function get_address() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

    geocoder.geocode({ address: "SE-17270 Sverige"}, 
    function(locResult) {

    var lat = locResult[0].geometry.location.lat();
    var lng = locResult[0].geometry.location.lng();

    thearray = [];
    thearray.push(lat);
    thearray.push(lng);
    return thearray;
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In header section add google library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

correct syntax errors and then start the function: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SkJdH/)

CODE (with jquery onload):

```
var lat = "";
var lng = "";

function getLatLng(callback) {
    lat = callback.lat();
    lng = callback.lng();
    alert(lat +" "+lng);
}

$(function() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder()

    geocoder.geocode({
        address: "SE-17270 Sverige"
    }, function(locResult) {
        getLatLng(locResult[0].geometry.location);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables `lat` and `lng` outside callback function.